# Twig Join, display 0 value

Tags: twig

I have an array of integers I am rendering with join in a twig template. If the value is zero, however, it is not displaying. Wondering if there is a way to resolve this easily?

Thanks

```
<b>Snow Last 24 Hours:</b> {{ report.snowLast24Hours|join(' - ') }} in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the suggested solutions seemed to work and the '0' values kept getting stripped. I worked around this by printing each individual value rather than using join.

ie.

```
{{ snow.min }} - {{ snow.max }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (with `join` and `replace`):

```
{{ (snowLast24Hours|join()|replace({'0':''}) is empty) ? '' : snowLast24Hours|join(' - ') }}
```

Or with `join` and `trim`:

```
{{ (snowLast24Hours|join()|trim('0') is empty) ? '' : snowLast24Hours|join(' - ') }}
```